# Form gets cleared on submitting a post request

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to prevent my form from being cleared on a post request in flask.
Here is my code:

predictor.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/util.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css">


</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="Formid">
<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="input" name="data_input" style="width:100%" maxlength="500"placeholder="Sepal length">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="input" name="data_input" style="width:100%" maxlength="500"placeholder="Sepal Width">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="input" name="data_input" style="width:100%" maxlength="500"placeholder="Petal length">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="input" name="data_input" style="width:100%" maxlength="500"placeholder="Petal Width">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" method="get"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
{{predictions}}
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the sample on submitting the form i get the output but the form values get cleared

Comment: Try setting the `value` attribute for each input field, where the value comes from a variable. Like `value="{{ some_variable }}"`.

Comment: values need to be inputted by the user

Comment: I have posted an answer, if you would require more information, I'll elaborate on it.

Comment: Use flask session and also pass the values from backend itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you need to preserve the values of other `input` fields in the form, if the form is unable to be processed due to one or more `input`(s) being invalid.

After the post request, store the values of the valid `input` fields in variables and pass them in the `value` attribute in the `input` tags so that the inputs of the form are prefilled on next reload.

Like this `<input type="text" value="{{ some_variable }}" />`

You can set these variables as empty strings initially for first-time input from users.

Comment: I need to preserve it even when the output gets displayed

Comment: Like i want the input values to be erased only when i myself click a reset button or something otherwise when i submit the form i want it to show the ans at the same time display the field values

Comment: You should try my solution and set/update the variables each time the form is submitted and the next time the form is loaded, it'll come pre-filled with the last input values. Set all the variables as empty strings, if a Reset button is clicked.

Comment: i dont understand how to assign a variable... can you give an example?